# python string functions not working for a column with datatype object

Tags: python, pandas, object, multiple-columns, dtype

I created a panda dataframe and am trying to split one of the columns (dtype = object) into multiple columns by separator.

I tried:

```
new = df["contract"].str.split(",", n=100, expand=True)

df[['Test2', 'conID', 'Test1', 'Expiration', 'Strike', 'Type', 'Multiplier', 'Exchange', 'Currency', 'Code', 'tradingClass']] = pd.DataFrame(df['contract'].tolist(), index=df.index)
df['contract_new'] = df['contract'].str.split(',') 
df['contract_new'] = df['contract'].astype('str')  
df['contract_new'] = df['contract'].str.replace('(', ',')
```

Below I have copied in the first three rows of the content of the panda df column with header 'contract'. It is a long field with 10 important data points which I need to be provided in different columns. The dataframe is retrieved from Interactive Brokers API.

```
    contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0   Option(conId=357974235, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2980.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02980000', tradingClass='SPX')   
1   Option(conId=357974238, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2985.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02985000', tradingClass='SPX')   
2   Option(conId=357974242, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2990.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02990000', tradingClass='SPX')
```

I would like to split the column with the 10 strings which are separated by the comma's into 10 separate columns, or perform other string based actions. In the end I want to see the following items in different columns:

```
-SPX
-201907192980.0
-P 
-100 
-SMART
-USD
-190719P02980000 (THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PART I NEED)
-SPX
```

So far nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Instead of bold font you can [use back ticks to fence in your example code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  It's usually easier to read that way.

Comment: Thanks for your input, apologies, I am a beginner on this.

Comment: Hi, could you provide some test data and the corresponding output, you would like to have, please?

Comment: @jottbe, I just edited my question to add the corresponding output I would like to receive. I just do not understand why normal string functions like split and replace do not work on this column.

Comment: If possible, please share the code of the `Option` class definition code.

Answer (score 2):

I just updated my answer. I try to use pandas operations since it seems you already have your data in a pandas DataFrame. The method should be reasonably robust regarding missing key-value pairs and their order in the input string:

```
import re
re_opt_start= re.compile('Option\(')
re_opt_end=   re.compile('\)\s*')
re_split=     re.compile('\s*,\s*')

df['contract']= df['contract'].str.replace(re_opt_start, '')
df['contract']= df['contract'].str.replace(re_opt_end, '')

df_split= df['contract'].str.split(',', expand=True)

result_df= None
for column in df_split:
    col_df= df_split[column].str.strip().str.split('=', expand=True)
    col_df.columns= ['col', 'value']
    col_df['value']= col_df['value'].str.strip("'")
    col_df.set_index('col', append=True, inplace=True)
    if result_df is None:
        result_df= col_df
    else:
        result_df= pd.concat([result_df, col_df], axis='index')

unstacked_df=result_df.unstack(level=-1).droplevel(0, axis='columns')
unstacked_df.loc[unstacked_df['localSymbol'].str[:3] == 'SPX', 'localSymbol']= unstacked_df['localSymbol'].str[3:]
unstacked_df
```

This returns:

```
Out[1285]: 
col      conId currency exchange lastTradeDateOrContractMonth  ... right  strike symbol tradingClass
0    357974235      USD    SMART                     20190718  ...     P  2980.0    SPX          SPX
1    357974238      USD    SMART                     20190718  ...     P  2985.0    SPX          SPX
2    357974242      USD    SMART                     20190718  ...     P  2990.0    SPX          SPX

[3 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for something different, can you please have a look in my edited question?

Comment: Thank's I updated it according your additional infos.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without regex by performing the following string manipulation (or something similar) on the data in each row. Using your first row as an example:

```
option = "conId=357974235, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2980.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02980000', tradingClass='SPX'"  

data = option.split(',')
to_delete = 0,3  #since apparently you aren't interested in 'conId' and 'strike'
for i in sorted(to_delete, reverse=True):
    del data[i]

for datum in data:
    if "localSymbol" in datum:
        datum = datum.replace('SPX   ','')
    print(datum.split('=')[1])
```

Output:

```
'SPX'
'20190718'
'P'
'100'
'SMART'
'USD'
'190719P02980000'
'SPX'
```

To automate the process, let's assume the data is stored like this:

```
option1 = "conId=357974235, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2980.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02980000', tradingClass='SPX'"  

option2 = "conId=357974238, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20190718', strike=2985.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   190719P02985000', tradingClass='SPX'"
```

etc. The code above is then modified as follows:

```
options = [option1, option2] #etc.

option_data = [] #this is a list of lists which will host all relevant data
to_delete = 0,3

for option in options:
    data = option.split(',')    
    for i in sorted(to_delete, reverse=True):
        del data[i]
    current_datum = [] #this is a one time list that will store data for the current item
    for datum in data:            
        if "localSymbol" in datum:
            datum = datum.replace('SPX   ','')
        current_datum.append(datum.split('=')[1])
    option_data.append(current_datum)
```

Finally, create the dataframe:

```
columns = ['symbol','last trade','right','multiplier','exchange','currency','local symbol','trading class']

df = pd.DataFrame(option_data, columns =columns) 
df
```

Output:

```
   symbol   last trade  right   multiplier  exchange    currency    local symbol    trading class
0   'SPX'   '20190718'  'P'     '100'   'SMART'     'USD'   '190719P02980000'   'SPX'
1   'SPX'   '20190718'  'P'     '100'   'SMART'     'USD'   '190719P02985000'   'SPX'
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, I will try this. Can this be done in an automated way for each row in the dataframe? Otherwise it will take too much time, there can be hundreds of rows and each data field will be different. And output I would like to store in new columns in the dataframe. Any ideas how to do that? Any idea why normal str.spli function is not working on the data fields in the contract column?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```py
def contract_to_columns(c):
  return pd.Series({"conId": c.conId, "symbol": c.symbol, "multiplier": c.multiplier, 
                    "lastTradeDateOrContractMonth": c.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth, 
                    "strike": c.strike, "right": c.right, "exchange": c.exchange, 
                    "currency": c.currency, "localSymbol": c.localSymbol.split()[1], 
                    "tradingClass": c.tradingClass})


df['contract'].apply(contract_to_columns)
```

output:
[image]

your `contract` column is an object, what you need is to do a mapping from contract object to multiple columns, notice that the column `localSymbol` has a prefix (*SPX*) you don't need, I removed it. 
This code depends also on the definition of class `Option`, if you want more help, please share the code of `Option` class.

Cheers

Comment: I added code for 'Option' class in the edit of your solution. The edit still needs to be peer reviewed however.

Comment: @FlorisvanK Please, don't add information on your question to answers of other people. Edit your own question

Comment: @FlorisvanK, hi, have you tried my code? The solution depends on how the object `Option` is defined. Can you share the `Option` class code in your question?